# Is there much difference in a RSA-4096 over RSA-3072 for support/speed and security?

Tags: rsa, key-size

I am in the process of created a signing certificate and i have an option of RSA-4096 or RSA-3072.
Is there much difference in security between the two? I know people say RSA-3072 should be good until 2030. But people may also prefer the high security.
But if it makes a big difference on speed, they may not.
So do you think it is worth using RSA-4096 for the next 10 years?

Comment: see [www.keylength.com](https://www.keylength.com/)

Comment: The biggest difference in speed you will see for the RSA key generation. For security, see kelalaka's link.

Comment: Formally, [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=31) does not support 4096-bit: "This Standard specifies three choices for the length of the modulus (i.e., _nlen_): 1024, 2048 and 3072 bits". And that might be a problem in some contexts. I have yet to meet any regulatory reason to exceed 3072-bit, and I seldom see a _technical_ reason to do so (an exception would be something that needs to remain secure for many decades _and_ a lot of care is used to make the data still exploitable at that time). But I sometime use 4096-bit as a paranoia damper.

Answer (score 2):

> I am in the process of created a signing certificate and i have an option of RSA-4096 or RSA-3072. Is there much difference in security between the two?

In my opinion, no, there is not a significant difference.

When considering RSA-3072, there are three potential future vulnerabilities:

- Someone amasses sufficient computing power to break a 3072-bit modulus using current algorithms
- Someone invents a new algorithm that works faster
- Someone builds a large and reliable Quantum Computer

As for the first one, well, the current algorithms would use circa $2^{128}$ computation effort to break it - we believe that is infeasible to anyone (and will remain so for quite a while)

As for the second one, that's hard to evaluate (and there's no indication that any future algorithm would find a 4096 bit modulus significantly harder).

As for Quantum Computers, well, that's the most realistic possibility.  In addition, we know that the size of Quantum Computer (and the amount of computation required) is not significantly larger for a 4096 bit modulus than it would be for a 3072 bit modulus; hence the additional work would not gain a significant amount of security.

So, the bottom line is that for the first and third possibility, there is little practical difference; the only difference would be in the second possibility, which is unknowable.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589834/what-rsa-key-length-should-i-use-for-my-ssl-certificates), they mention that there is not particularly good software support for RSA-3072.

Comment: That answer is from a long time ago, I'd take it with a grain of salt.  The 3K response is certainly not correct these days, e.g. both OpenSSL and BouncyCastle support that and I've got FIPS validated modules for that.